# azure ki text to speech phonetic spelling is missing

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, phoneme

a few weeks ago, we noticed that the phoneme adaptation of the phonetic transcription in azure ki text to speech no longer contains a phonetic transcription. you would now have to "build" the word yourself via phonetic transcription instead of changing small details in the existing phonetic transcription. do some one else notice that? and also, if you do it by yourself and save it and want to edit later something, the word, which you have changed is still underlined with red, but the existing field is emtpy.